# Has anyone set up an API for a group of users in BeyondTrust,

Tags: api, rest, password-manager

Has anyone set up an API for a group of users in BeyondTrust, and if so, will the members of the group be able to see and access each others passwords or do I need to create separate API Keys per each user?

I have not tried this as of yet, I do not fully understand the results of attempting an API for a group of users with in BeyondTrust Password Management systems, and I am afraid if I set up an API for a group of users, they will be able to view and utilize passwords that do not belong to them.

Is an API for a group even a thing, or do I have to set up API keys per user?

Answer (score 0):

Password Safe users can use the API to do most of the functions available through the UI. They operate under the same security model regardless of access method, with the caveat that accounts need to be indicated as accessible via the API. This means that you might not be able access every account that you have access to through the UI, via the API but, it does mean you cannot access any account through the API that you don't have access to through the UI.